Bottom navigation is not persistent in Flutter app
I have added a bottom navigation to my Flutter web app. I also have a sidedrawer with other menu items.
The bottom nav bar works great but if I click on any of the links in the side drawer I lose the bottom nav bar and when I click back I am taken to the login page and not the previous page.
When the user logs into the app, they are taken to the main_screen which has the BottomNavigationBar.
Here is the code for main_screen.dart:
  final List<Widget> appScreens = [
    const CompanyDashboardScreen(),
    const TransactionDetailScreen(true, true),
    const AppointmentCalendarScreen(),
    const UserProfileScreen(),
    const ChatScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      ensureScreenSize: true,
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: const CustomAppBar(),
          body: SafeArea(child: Container(child: appScreens[_pageIndex])),
          drawer: const SideDrawer(),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.red),
            selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.black45,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            currentIndex: _pageIndex,
            onTap: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _pageIndex = value;
              });
              if (value == 3) {
                ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewUser(false);
              }
            },

            ///
            /// Bottom Navigation Bar items
            ///
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.house), label: "Home"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.fileInvoiceDollar),
                  label: "Trxn"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendar), label: "Calendar"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.person), label: "User Profile"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), label: 'Chat'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Added this for BottomNavigationBar sync
  void setIndex(int index) {
    if (mounted) setState(() => _pageIndex = index);
  }
}

///
/// Side drawer menu items
///
class SideDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: (ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: Text("$userFName $userLName"),
            accountEmail: Text(auth.currentUser!.email ?? 'No Email Found'),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.add_business,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                title: const Text('Edit Company'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const CompanyScreen(false)));
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
                title: const Text('Add Company Agent'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const UserProfileScreen(true),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.account_balance,
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
                title: const Text('View Mortgage Companies'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          const ListOfMortgageCompaniesScreen(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.person_outline_sharp,
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                ),
                title: const Text('View Clients'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const ListOfClientsScreen(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.businessTime),
                title: const Text('View Title Companies'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const ListOfTitleCompaniesScreen(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.personWalking),
                title: const Text('View Appraiser Companies'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          const ListOfAppraiserCompaniesScreen(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.peopleCarryBox),
                title: const Text('View Inspector Companies'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          const ListOfInspectorCompaniesScreen(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.calculator),
                title: const Text('Mortgage Calculator'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              const MortgageCalculatorScreen()));
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.dollarSign),
                title: const Text('Pricing'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              const MortgageCalculatorScreen()));
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.lock),
                title: const Text(
                  'Privacy Policy',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue, decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  if (kIsWeb) {
                    _launchInBrowser();
                  } else {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const PrivacyPolicyScreen()));
                  }
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.logout,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                title: const Text('Log Out'),
                onTap: () {
                  // Update the state of the app
                  signOut();
                  // Then close the drawer
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

So, how do I get the pages that are displayed from the sidedrawer to still show the bottom nav bar?
How do I get the pages displayed from the sidedrawer menu to go back to the previous page when I click the back button?

instead of navigating to other pages directly from drawer
update index of screen from drawer tiles
